# Is there a method to access hidden files from ASP.NET Server?

Tags: html, asp.net, server

I'm trying to create a mobile application for my school's Gradebook system, as their current website design is quite unattractive. I don't want to scrape the information directly off the HTML in the website because it seems slow and inefficient, so I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the raw data that the website retrieves before displaying it as HTML content.

The website will call something like `https://.../RetrieveReport`, and an HTML page will immediately be returned to the client side. I'm wondering if there is any way to peer into the handler on the asp.net side to understand where it is getting the raw data from. Please let me know if this is possible. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not legally, afaik. Btw, what does the data have to do with the attractiveness? Use fake data if you want to update the style.

Comment: You'd need to see the source code of the website. But even then if you knew where the data comes from, unless the server has horrendous security issues it's very unlikely your app would be able to access any of it directly. Most likely it's in a database which should not be exposed to the internet